# How to reassemble Trek 820 rear wheel?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, hub, trek

In the process of replacing my gear cassette on my Trek 820 bike I took apart my rear wheel hub and bearings and I have no clue how the parts are supposed to go back together.[image: rear wheel hub parts]

Comment: How did you get here???? [All you need to replace a cassette is a cassette tool, chain whip and a wrench.](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal-and-installation#article-section-3)

Comment: Where are the ball bearings?  Still in the hub?

Comment: @Criggie - They were in the hub.  Until he cleaned it out.

Comment: Generally speaking, its a great idea to take photos as you disassemble things.

Comment: @Criggie - Just don't use your shop rag to wipe the camera lens.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'd get my beautiful assistant to take the photos, but he's all paws.   Another option is to get up a gopro or similar and just record the whole session, holding things up to the lens for a closeup.